# How to implode a query result inside a mysql5 stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to implode a query result using `","` inside my mysql stored procedure. How can I do that?

For example,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE mysp()

BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  temp;
    CREATE TABLE temp (ids INT(11) , typeid INT(11));

   INSERT INTO temp SELECT id,typeid FROM table_mine1 ..etc

   INSERT INTO temp SELECT id,typeid FROM table_mine2 ..etc
```

After this I want to fetch all "ids" from temp table and make it as comma separated.

Because I need to write one another query like this

```
DELETE FROM main_table WHERE ids NOT IN (comma separated ids of temp table.)
```

How to implode ids of my temp table using comma?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [GROUP_CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)?
something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR ',') FROM temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this -

```
DELETE mt FROM
  main_table mt
LEFT JOIN temp t
  ON mt.id = t.id
WHERE
  t.id IS NULL;
```

This query will delete all records in main_table which does not exist in temp table. There is no need in comma separated ids.